# Why use chained prototype inheritance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-programming

[perf](http://jsperf.com/object-inheritance-vs-object-composition)

Why do we build a prototype inheritance chain rather then using object composition. Looking up through the prototype for each step in the chain get's expensive.

Here is some dummy example code :

```
var lower  = {
    "foo": "bar"
};

var upper = {
    "bar": "foo"
};

var chained = Object.create(lower,  pd(upper));

var chainedPrototype = Object.create(chained);

var combinedPrototype = Object.create(pd.merge(lower, upper));

var o1 = Object.create(chainedPrototypes);
var o2 = Object.create(combinedPrototypes);
```

uses [`pd`](https://github.com/Raynos/pd#Documentation) because property descriptors are verbose as hell.

`o2.foo` is faster then `o1.foo` since it only goes up two prototype chain rather then three.

Since travelling up the prototype chain is expensive why do we construct one instead of using object composition?

Another better example would be :

```
var Element = {
  // Element methods
}

var Node = {
  // Node methods
}

var setUpChain = Object.create(Element, pd(Node));
var chained = Object.create(setUpChain);
var combined = Object.create(pd.merge(Node, Element));

document.createChainedElement = function() {
  return Object.create(chained);
}

document.createCombinedElement = function() {
  return Object.create(combined);
}
```

I do not see any code merging prototype objects for efficiency. I see a lot of code building chained prototypes. Why is the latter more popular?

The only reason I can think of is using `Object.isPrototypeOf` to test for individual prototypes in your chain.

Apart from `isPrototypeOf` are there clear advantages to using inheritance over composition?

Comment: Note that one of the optimizations every self-respecting JIT-compiler (and not only in JS, e.g. PyPy does that for Python objects - and Python's object attribute lookup is even more complex!) looks for common object layouts and lookup chains and optimizes access to directly compute the offset. See http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2010/11/efficiently-implementing-python-objects.html which explains the general idea (in a class-based setting) and links to resources on similar optimizations in other JIT-compilers (e.g. V8). Your benchmark confirms that there's little difference between o1 and o2.

Comment: @delnan would you think worrying about the extra computational cost of going up the prototype chain is a micro optimisation we should not care about?

Comment: That and even more - it's an micro-optimization when using a brain-dead interpreter. When using a good JIT-compiler (and those become more common and even better every year), it's completely possible are there won't be any difference at all (after JIT warmup, of course).

Comment: @Raynos, I do think it is micro optimization, because there are clear benefits to using prototypes (memory utilization and instanceof). If you find that there's some object where the lookup is a bottleneck, then you should go ahead and optimize that part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason would have to be changes to the prototype object. A change to an ancestor object will be reflected across the entire chain. This could, conceivably, be a benefit. Though I can't immediately think of any real-world instances, I think embracing this dynamic nature could provide a dynamic that other (read: class-based) languages simply don't provide.

Objects further up the prototype chain could evolve as needed across the lifetime of an application, and those changes would be reflected across all descendant objects. This could be easily combined with JavaScript's functions as first-class objects to dynamically modify functionality as needed.

That said, if this functionality is not necessary, there is no reason to use the prototype chain over composition.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about objects not being pass by reference.

Comment: @Raynos They are passed by reference, but you are copying object properties, rather than looking it up through the referenced prototype?

Answer (score 0):

Well, consider what would happen if `lower` or `upper` changed. The combined prototype wouldn't reflect that change since you've created a new object by copying properties from them.

For many situations that would be fine, but it's sure not as dynamic as actually constructing proper prototype chains for your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some benefits I can think of in order of importance

#### Memory usage

By using the prototype, you create shared properties. Your approach copies all the values to each object.

#### Upfront cost of setting up objects

Thought you are saving a little bit of time later, you are incurring the cost of copying properties when you set up the object. It'd be nice for you to account for that in your performance tests. This is a benefit that may be outweighed if you read a lot more than you set up your objects.

#### instanceOf

Good code doesn't use instanceOf, but sometimes you can't make all your code perfect, so why break a language feature?

#### Dynamically changing the prototype

Most people will claim that they never need this (like me), but many of us have extended Array.prototype after instantiating some arrays (not that you should do it). With the copy properties approach you lose the reference to the original object.

Unashamed plug: http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

**Last Note** If you this is actually a bottleneck in an app, I would not be reluctant to use it for the objects in question

Comment: Memory usage has very little difference and is implementation specific.

Comment: isPrototypeOf can still be used in the combined case. Except each object can only be on type.