# Why use object inheritance instead of mixins

Tags: oop, inheritance, language-agnostic, composition, mixins

[gist](https://gist.github.com/1223378)

What are the reasons to favour inheritance over mixins

Given the following psuedo-code example :

```
class Employee

class FullTimeEmployee inherits Employee

class PartTimeEmployee inherits Employee

// versus

class Employee

class WorksPartTime

class WorksFullTime

class FullTimeEmployee includes Employee, WorksFullTime
class PartTimeEmployee includes Employee, WorksPartTime
```

If we were to use inheritance to build objects the class relations would be seen as a tree where as with mixins the class relations would be seen as a flat list.

Assuming the language we are using

- allows for mixins with a non-verbose syntax
- allows us to treat `FullTimeEmployee` as both a `Employee` and `FullTime` object transparently.

why should we build up our class relations as trees (inheritance) instead of flat lists (composition)?

Example of tree versus list.

```
class Person

class Employee inherits Person

class FullTimeEmployee inherits Employee

//                      -> FullTimeEmployee
//  Person -> Employee
//                      -> PartTimeEmployee

class Person

class Employee includes Person

class FullTime

class FullTimeEmployee includes FullTime, Employee

//
// FullTimeEmployee = (FullTime, Employee, Person)
//
```

Comment: Would you consider this a duplicate of [Why use inheritance at all?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351666/why-use-inheritance-at-all) ?

Comment: @daxelrod no because that's comparing inheritance to delegation and it also doesn't answer my question. My question is mainly about building class relations as trees versus flat lists.

Comment: What are FullTime and PartTime when they're not associated with Employee?

Comment: @TerryWilcox I believe loose coupling of `FullTime` from `Employee` is a habit of over engineering on my part

Comment: Then I think you've answered your own question. Prefer composition over inheritance, but use inheritance when it makes sense. FullTimeEmployee makes more sense as a subclass of Employee than it does as an Employee with a FullTime.

Comment: @TerryWilcox the question is "when does it make sense". Why does it make more sense as a subclass then an Employee with FullTime. Does changing the wording to "WorksFullTime" make combining "Employee" and "WorksFullTime" more reasonable?

Comment: @Raynos Neither FullTime nor WorksFullTime make sense as objects. An Employee doesn't have a WorksFullTime and a WorksFullTime is a what? Would you ever use it in the absence of an Employee? I'd prefer Inheritance over bad design in the name of Composition.

Comment: @TerryWilcox a WorksFullTime is an object that implements methods to do with working full time. And it should read as FullTimeEmployee is a union of WorksFullTime and Employee. You may be confusing composition with mixins. I should change all references to composition to mixin. Once again the loose coupling of WorksFullTime from Employee may be overengineering or it's a simple case of a bad example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that in languages that do support mixins, it is effectively the same as using (multiple) inheritance.  In both cases, the same methods/properties exist on the class/object in question, both are invoked the exact same way -- there is no practical distinction. I'm also assuming that in this hypothetical language, you can 'extend' from multiple 'classes' as well.

If this is all true, then in a way they are equivalent and the question doesn't make sense - neither is better than the other because they are functionality equivalent.

In a human-understanding sort of way, I think most people think of inheritance in terms of the `isA` relationship, and mixins in terms of decorating something with functionality.

If you can only inherit from one 'class', then obviously mixins are a way to sort of gain  multiple inheritance.

EDIT -- based on your comments, which are good, I would say the details of the hypothetical language matter.   I will admit I am basing my answer of the Sproutcore, which is a Javascript framework that has formalized support for both mixins and inheritance.  In SC, you can do

```
App.MyObject = SC.Object.extend({
  prop: 'prop',
  func: function(){
})
```

which does what you would expect, it puts `prop` and `func` on the prototype of `MyObject`, creating a "class", which could have subclasses.  You could also do

```
App.MyObject = SC.Object.extend(App.OtherObject, {
   // stuff
})
```

which does multiple inheritance.  You could then have something like

```
CommonFunctionality = {
    // some methods
};

App.mixin(CommonFunctionality);
```

which would apply the `CommonFunctionality` stuff to `App`.  If app was a namespace (i.e. a `{}`) the methods of `CommonFunctionality` would be applied to that object literal.  If it made sense, you could also apply `CommonFunctionality` to a "class", and its methods would be on the prototype. If you look in the source, you see

`SC.extend = SC.mixin ;`

So in SC, there is absolutely no difference because they are the same method.

So details matter -- they didn't have to do it that way, but they did, and there are implications.  If they had done it differently, then of course there would be different consequences.

Comment: The main difference is chaining. Why would you set up an inheritance chain/tree when you can just have a flat list or linked list.

Comment: Also how are mixins different from classical inheritance in popular implementations? Am I confusing how mixins work?

Comment: [I already know the value of inheritance & composition in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294276/why-use-chained-prototype-inheritance-in-javascript) but that's prototypical inheritance instead of classical inheritance. Which is a different ball game. Also in SC `extend` is not inheritance. It's just another name for `mixin`.

Comment: right, but extend adds the stuff in the argument to the prototype, so its creating a 'class'. class in quotes, because of the prototypical inheritance.  That's my point, there is little difference between 'mixing something in' and 'extending'

Comment: links to source. Again the main difference is that extension is a live link, where as mixed in objects are static shallow clones.

Answer (score 0):

You should use when the necessity appears. If you have a big class with 1000 lines and you are finding yourself repeating the same stuff across multiple classes you can encapsulate some logic in a base class and other in mixins. Each mixin has a limited context, they might be aware about more than they should, but they only focus on a certain task. Therefore are very modular.
Well, the best example I can give it to you is an [Actor for a game](http://www.webdesignporto.com/game-actor-class/) which has inheritance for some base stuff but uses [mixins](http://www.webdesignporto.com/javascript-classes-and-inheritance/#mixins)/[plugins](http://www.webdesignporto.com/single-visual-entity-plugin-for-actor/) for shared functionality. The shared functionality could be (directly from the source code!):

```
var plugins = {
    SingleVisualEntity : SingleVisualEntity,
    JumpBehaviour      : JumpBehaviour,
    WeaponBehaviour    : WeaponBehaviour,
    RadarBehaviour     : RadarBehaviour,
    EnergyGatherer     : EnergyGatherer,
    LifeBarPlugin      : LifeBarPlugin,
    SelectionPlugin    : SelectionPlugin,
    UpgradePlugin      : UpgradePlugin,
    BrainPlugin        : BrainPlugin,
    PlanetObjectPlugin : PlanetObjectPlugin,
}
```

This originally was a class with +1000 lines.

Answer (score -1):

**When designing we try to simulate reality as much as we can.**

Considering the `is a` and the `has a` principles, a `FullTimeEmployee is an Employee` who has additional (extra) feature, and **not** some new thing that `has an Employee` beside something called `FullTime`, and so on for the `PartTimeEmployee`.

Comment: mixins are not `has an`. If `FullTimeEmployee` had a field named `Employee` then that's a `has an` relation.

Comment: @Raynos: If `FullTimeEmployee` had a field named `Employee` then logically he would no longer be an `Employee`, but something that `has a` or includes an `Employee`. another Example is that a `Taxi` is a `car` that has some specifiactions, we can't say that a `Taxi has a car`, that is not reasonable.